# jquery (touch) toggle/slider settings window

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, jqtouch

Im using phonegap + jquery 
+ jquery iphone touch: http://www.midemos.com/demos/iphone/touch/?/iphone/touch/

Im trying to get something like this:
("quakeprediction" tweet slider)

[image]

I basically want to hide a settings window outside the screen.

When you slide to the left (enough) it animates "elasticly" from outside the window.

Small jsfiddle visually displaying the principle: http://jsfiddle.net/FzJZk/2/

Because the jquery iphone touch plugin i use ( http://www.midemos.com/demos/iphone/touch/?/iphone/touch/ )  doesn't support mouse events jsfiddle isn't going to work for "realworld example".

Here is the jsfiddle version of the latest code i have:

http://jsfiddle.net/kgGes/
It slides fine, however it doesn't have that "elastic string effect" animation.
When i set "animate: true," it just gives white borders on the left and right, no smooth animation. "sticky: true" doesn't change anything.

Please don't come up with examples using jQuery UI, i like the extremely small footprint of the jquery iphone touch plugin i'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/SwipeView/demo/inline/